# Как называется данный шаблон проектирования в Spring

Tags: java, spring, шаблоны-проектирования

Я начал разрабатывать вебсайт с использованием Spring Boot (2.2.6.RELEASE) + Hibernate и столкнулся с тем, что мне надо выбрать паттерн для разработки вебсайта.

Я выбрал следующий вариант для разработки, но не могу понять как называется такой паттерн (предполагаю, что MVC):

```
@Entity -> @Repository -> @Service -> @Controller <- HTML(Thymeleaf/Template Engine)
```

То есть я создаю сущности/модели (@Entity)
Для работы с таблицами я использую `extend CrudRepository<..., ...>` (@Repository)
Бизнес-логику записываю в сервис-класс, где я с помощью `@Autowired` имею доступ к `Repository` (@Service)
В контроллере я с помощью `@Autowired` получаю доступ к `@Service` и в контроллере я указываю какой `template` мне надо использовать для той или иной страницы(@Controller).
Пример:

@Entity

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "role_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="role_generator", sequenceName = "seq_role", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String roleName;

    //Еще  какой-то код
}
```

@Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Long> {

    List<Role> findAll();

    Role findByRoleName(String roleName);
}
```

@Service

```java
@Service
public class RegistrationService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public Viewer findByRoleName(String roleName) {
        return roleRepository.findByRoleName(roleName);
    }
}
```

@Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/registration")
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView getRegistration(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("public/registration");
        modelAndView.addObject("users", registrationService.findByRoleName("TEST").getUsers());
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

*Примеры лишь отображают идею, поэтому ошибок в коде не ищите*

Comment: не все так просто. паттернов проектирования огромное количество, все не ограничивается только GOF. В вашем случае и Service layer, и repository, и mvc , как и многое другое, являются паттернами (указанные относятся к enterprise ). Если копнуть глубже, то, к примеру в mvc, о котором вы говорили, отношение модели и вьюхи построено на наблюдателе (а это уже gof) , а, например, сам контроллер - не что иное как имплементация одноименного паттерна grasp. их гораздо больше,чем вы думаете и они почти везде))

Comment: @Дмитрий Я соглашусь, что паттернов много, но как называется тот, что я привел выше?

Comment: так я вам и ответил на этот вопрос. то, что делаете вы, не описывается одним паттерном. их тут целый зоопарк. и mvc в этот зоопарк , разумеется, входит. мало того, на примере mvc я вам показал, что он тоже состоит из паттернов (сам mvc)

Comment: @Дмитрий Я вас понял...